# Angular + Firebase - Component not keeping authentication state on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

*Hello*, I'm trying to build simple authentication service for my Angular app using Firebase. The problem is that - the user can login/register and I'm able to save his credentials inside the local storage. However, when I refresh the page the info inside the Local Storage remains there, but my components are showing the view that is supposed to be for the users that are not logged in( so my authentication state is equal to logged out ). If I don't refresh the page everything is working the way is supposed to be. Here is my Auth Service(auth.service.ts):

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

interface User{
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  signedin$ = new BehaviorSubject(false)
  userData

  constructor(public firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe((user)=>{
      if(user){
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }else{
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })
  }

  signup(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        this.router.navigate(['auth/login'])
        console.log('Success!', value);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      });
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.firebaseAuth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.signedin$.next(true)
        console.log('Nice, it worked!', result);
        return result
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      });
  }

  logout() {
    return this.firebaseAuth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.signedin$.next(false)
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['movies']);
    })
  }

}
```

This is my **App.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth2/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  signedin;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.signedin$
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.signedin = data
      })
  }

  logOut() {
    this.authService.logout()
    this.authService.signedin$
      .subscribe((signedInData) => {
        this.signedin = signedInData
      })
  }

}
```

Inside the Core/App/Main Component I want to check for the user stats - logged in/logged out. So I'm subscribing to the Behavior Subject inside the Auth Service. I've tried different variations, but none of them is working. I hope there is any solution. I have not yet implemented any Auth Guards. Is this problem that is causing my component view to crash whenever I refresh the page ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for asking the question in such a neat way.

The problem in your code is when you refresh, the behaviour subject you have defined will not save it's state as the service class will also start from beginning.

You will have to check the local storage to know if the user is logged in or not as only there loggedIn user info will be present.

create a method in auth.service

```
isUserSignedIn(){
if(localstorage.getItem('user')){ return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

Now in the component `this.authService.isUserSignedIn()`

also if you want the whole user info return that from function instead of Boolean true/false.

```
return localstorage.getItem('user')
```